# How to add a CSS class to sibling component's elements?

Tags: angular, typescript

I have two components **A** and **B**. **A** has a button, when clicked I want to add a class `c` to component **B**'s element (for example `<div></div>`).I have tried `@Input` and making function static, use that in other component. It is not working.

Comment: Can you post some codes to help us to understand why it's not working?

Comment: I think the problem was something else which I found out lately. The problem is CSS class is not applying on the childnodes. For example the code is look like this:
var x=document.getelementbyId("text").childnodes;
var y=x[0] as HTMLElement;
y.classList.add("c");

where "text" is a div and childnodes are span.

Answer (score 0):

You can provide an event as `@Output` in you component **A** and listen to that output. If that event gets triggered you can set your class 'c' with `ngClass` on component **B**.

Component A:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-component-a',
  templateUrl: './app-component-a.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app-component-a.component.scss']
})
export class ComponentA implements OnInit {
  @Output() onClickEvent: Event;

  ngOnInit() {
  }

  onClick() {
    event.emit();
  }
}
```

Main Component:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-main-component',
  templateUrl: './app-main-component.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app-main-component.component.scss']
})
export class MainComponent implements OnInit {

  whenClicked: boolean = false;

  ngOnInit() {
  }

  onClickTriggered() {
    whenClicked = true;
  }
}
```

Main Component HTML:

```
<app-component-a (onClickEvent)="onClickTriggered()"></app-component-a>
<app-component-b [ngClass]="{'c': whenClicked}"
```